# Selectively suppress error messages - Disable msg: 2114 in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, error-handling

Does anyone know if we can selectively suppress SMS error messages sent by the carrier ?

We have an app that auto replies to users. Only on the Sprint network we get a text msg: 2114 when the app auto replies to a phone call with a SMS message.

This thread describes our issue in detail:
http://community.sprint.com/baw/thread/82947

Thanks in advance ..